# Filemaker XSL - inconsistent number of photo nodes in imported XML

Tags: xml, xslt, addition, nodes, filemaker

I have an XML file like this which I need to import into a Filemaker database.

```
<propertys>
 <property>
  <ref>12345</ref>
  <photos>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
  </photos>
 </property>
 <property>
  <ref>54321</ref>
  <photos>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
  </photos>
 </property>
 <property>
  <ref>67890</ref>
  <photos>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
   <photo>http://www.url.com/image.jpg</photo>
  </photos>
 </property>
</propertys>
```

As you can see, there is an inconsistent number of photos per property.

I need to fit this into the following Filemaker XSLT import structure, which has to give an output of 36 photo rows per property whether there are 36 photos or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
  <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
  <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 12.0v4"/>
  <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT=""/>
  <METADATA>
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Ref" TYPE="TEXT" />             
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image1" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image2" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image3" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image4" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image5" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image6" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image7" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image8" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image9" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image10" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image11" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image12" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image13" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image14" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image15" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image16" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image17" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image18" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image19" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image20" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image21" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image22" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image23" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image24" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image25" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image26" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image27" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image28" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image29" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image30" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image31" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image32" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image33" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image34" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image35" TYPE="TEXT" />
    <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Image36" TYPE="TEXT" />
  </METADATA>

  <RESULTSET FOUND="">
   <xsl:for-each select="propertys/property">
      <ROW RECORDID="" MODID="">

        <!-- REF -->
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ref"/></DATA></COL>

        <!-- here I need to output 36 rows whether the property has 36 photos or not to match the Filemaker definition -->
        <COL><DATA></DATA></ROW> <!-- IMAGE 1 -->
        <COL><DATA></DATA></ROW> <!-- IMAGE 2 -->
        .... etc
     </ROW>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

If anyone could help me understand this, it would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do **not** need to create 36 COLs for each ROW. Having declared 36 FIELDs in the METADATA section is enough. Try this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="Ref" TYPE="TEXT" />             
            <FIELD NAME="Image1" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image2" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image3" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image4" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image5" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image6" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image7" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image8" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image9" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image10" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image11" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image12" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image13" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image14" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image15" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image16" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image17" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image18" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image19" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image20" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image21" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image22" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image23" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image24" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image25" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image26" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image27" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image28" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image29" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image30" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image31" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image32" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image33" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image34" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image35" TYPE="TEXT" />
            <FIELD NAME="Image36" TYPE="TEXT" />
        </METADATA>
        <RESULTSET FOUND="">
            <xsl:for-each select="propertys/property">
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="ref"/></DATA></COL>
                    <xsl:for-each select="photos/photo">
                        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="."/></DATA></COL>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Note:

**Having 36 identical fields is bad database structure**. You should have a related table for the photos, where each photo would be a separate record. Then each property can have **any** number of photos.

---

### Added:

> Say I have two tables in Filemaker: Properties and Images. They are
>   linked on a unique number ID field, PropID, which is created in
>   Filemaker as records are added. How would I import using Filemaker's
>   XML import step using the above XML and XSL and get the photos and
>   data separately and into the correct tables?

This is by no means the only way to do this, but that's what I would do:

1. Import the photos into the `Images` table, routing `ref` to a `Images::TempPropertyID` field.
2. Import the imported images into the `Properties` table, routing `Images::TempPropertyID` to `Properties::TempPropertyID`; the `Properties::TempPropertyID` field needs to be validated as Unique, Validate always.
3. Use an auxiliary relationship between the two tables, based on matching `TempPropertyID`, to populate the (real) `Images::PropertyID` field with the value of the matching  `Properties::PropertyID` (auto-entered during the import to Properties).
4. At this point, you probably should erase the contents of the `TempPropertyID` fields in both imported sets, to prevent collision with subsequent imports that might use the same ref number to refer to another property.

Comment: That's great. I didn't realise it was that simple. Thanks very much.

In my database, the photos are split into a related database but all the data has to come into a holding database to be edited before it is launched into the live database.

Comment: This xml file (and others) are provided in this format by external agents for updating of our real estate data.

Comment: @TVRV8S I understand that. I just believe that having a single photo field in the target table (even if it's a temp table) would be more convenient. The XML file itself does not dictate this or other structure of the target table - you can use XSLT to transform it as required (that's the whole idea behind XSLT).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Say I have two tables in Filemaker: Properties and Images. They are linked on a unique number ID field, PropID, which is created in Filemaker as records are added.

How would I import using Filemaker's XML import step using the above XML and XSL and get the photos and data separately and into the correct tables?

I don't know how to do this. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. XML is quite new to me.

Comment: @TVRV8S I have added the rather lengthy explanation to my answer.